# What would be the jar & driver class to be used while connecting to Greenplum using Spark to read data?

Tags: apache-spark, greenplum

I'm trying to connect to Greenplum database using Spark to read data from a table and save it as a file on HDFS. But I am facing hurdles with the driver or connector I am using. Below is my build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11" % "provided",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3"
)
```

I am passing the greenplum connector from spark-submit as below:

```
  try {
Class.forName("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider").newInstance()
  }
  catch {
    case cnf: ClassNotFoundException =>
      println("No class def found.")
      System.exit(1)
    case e: Exception =>
      println("No class def found.")
      System.exit(1)
  }


val yearDF = spark.read.format("greenplum").option("url", connectionUrl)
        .option("dbtable", "gptable")
        .option("dbschema","gpschema")
        .option("user", username)
        .option("password", password)
        .option("partitionColumn","id")
        .option("partitions",450)
        .load()
        .where("period=2017 and month=12")
        .select(colSeq map col:_*)
println(yearDF.count)
```

Spark-submit command:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --class com.partition.source.PartitionData --master=yarn --conf spark.ui.port=4090 --driver-class-path /home/etluser/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar --conf spark.jars=/home/etluser/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 13G --keytab /home/etluser/etluser.keytab --principal etluser@HDPDEV.COM --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,connection.properties --name TEST_YEAR --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/etluser/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar testYear_2.11-0.1.jar
```

**colSeq** is a collection which contains data of column & datatype each separated by a comma.

When I run the job, it doesn't progress at all and instead, it ends with "No such element exception".

I referred the code from the [link](https://github.com/kongyew/greenplum-spark-connector/blob/master/usecase1/README.MD) and the official greenplum documentation give [here](https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/160/read_from_gpdb.html).
Is this is a connector(greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar) issue or a driver issue ? Could anyone let me know if the jars used are correct ones ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the latest spark connector v.1.6.0?

Second, you can try using your code without "partitions" as partitions parameter is optional ?

Also, it will be easier to debug this issue if you can provide full stack trace .

Link: https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/160/index.html

Answer (score -1):

You can go through the link below :

https://medium.com/@priya.chauhangfi/connect-to-ibm-db2-data-base-with-pyspark-in-hdfs-shell-environment-c0109926fd

Replace the IBM driver with greenplum driver